# Ссылка на страницу работает не коректно

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, php-nginx

Изучаю php, возникла проблема. Использую фраемворк phalcon, делаю окно регистрации пользователя используя view & controllers. Проблема происходит при переходе со стартовой страницы на страницу регистрации. Если сделать намеренно опечатку в коде, то страница регистрации показывается (вместе с ошибками), если же правильно написать код, то страница регистрации вообще не показывается, ссылка не переводит на регистрацию а снова показывает стартовую страницу. В чем проблема? Может я не правильно сконфигурировал сервер?
[image: форма регистрации с ошибкой в коде]
[image: форма регистрации без ошибки в коде]

UPD: Вот код контроллера IndexController.php:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //echo '<h1>Hello!</h1>';
    }
}
```

И код контроллера SignupController.php:

```
<?php
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class SignupController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

    }
    public function registerAction()
    {
        $user = new Users();

        // Store and check for errors
        $success = $user->save(
            $this->request->getPost(),
            [
                "name",
                "email",
            ]
        );

        if ($success) {
            echo "Thanks for registering!";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, the following problems were generated: ";

            $messages = $user->getMessages();

            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                echo $message->getMessage(), "<br/>";
            }
        }

        $this->view->disable();
    }
}
```

Файла .htaccess у меня нет, я использую NGINX

Comment: код в студию. Контроллер, .htaccess, роутинг.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение проблемы. В папке /tutorial.dev/app/view у меня было так:
signup
index.phtml

А должно было быть 2 папки:
signup
index

В каждой из них находится соответствующий index.phtml. У меня по тому и высвечиваль все время стартовая страница, потому что я не разместил ее index.phtml в папке.